# Multiple SQL Selects to use values to further the search

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL query that gets a single row from the database. I want to ultimately return that row plus additional data that can be searched for with values from the first query's row. The only inital data I have is the magazineId. We will use 41659.

```
select productid, dispenserid from magazine where magazineid = 41659
```

Gives me two important data values to work with, in one row: ProductID and dispenserId...

```
Select MagazineID, dispenserId, ProductID  from Magazine where ProductID = *** ProductID *** and dispenserId = ***dispenserId***
```

I ultimately want to get a new row(s), that is generated by doing searches that give me the data to work with in the first query.

How can one do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use subqueries:

```
SELECT MagazineID, DispenserID, ProductID
FROM Magazine
WHERE ProductID = (SELECT ProductID 
                   FROM Magazine
                   WHERE MagazineID= 41659)
  AND DispenserId = (SELECT DispenserID 
                     FROM Magazine
                     WHERE MagazineID= 41659)
```

Though I'm not sure why you can't just do this:

```
SELECT MagazineID, DispenserID, ProductID
FROM Magazine
WHERE MagazineID = 41659
```

Comment: But why, when joins seem so much more elegant?

Comment: @Strawberry Joins work too. I was just trying to give some answer. The question and what he's really trying to select are worded confusingly to me.

Comment: In which case, say so, and vote to close accordingly. It may prompt the op to improve their question

Comment: Well. I think that this could actually be helpful to them. If it's not, I would hope they'd say why this doesn't work or clarify their question. At least it's a starting point.

Comment: Actually I think this is what the OP was looking for.

Comment: Both Dan and Tom's answers work perfectly with what I needed. I didn't know I needed to Select again on a column.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the magazine with the given ID will certainly match by `DispenserID` and `ProductID`, so you can simply do this:

```
SELECT
    M2.MagazineID,
    M2.DispenserID,
    M2.ProductID
FROM
    Magazine M1
INNER JOIN Magazine M2 ON
    M2.DispenserID = M1.DispenserID AND
    M2.ProductID = M1.ProductID
WHERE
    M1.MagazineID = 41659
```